# "'int' object is not iterable" - How to iterate over an integer?

Tags: python

The line `single_true_false = digits // 10**single % 10` is giving me an

```
unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'
```

exception. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Also, is there a more pythonic or productive way to write my code in general? I am new to python so I would really appreciate the help

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file: 
    open_file = file.read()
    
satisfied = 0 
not_satisfied = 0 #still need to check if it is alpha!!!!
distinct = {x.rstrip() for x in open_file} #distinct = (variable for variable in open_file if not variable in distinct)
length = len(distinct) #list

for i in range(0,2**length): 
    binary = bin(i) 
    removed = binary[2:] #removing "0b" prefix
    digits = f"removed:length"   
    true_false = ()
    
    for single in range(0,length): #See slide 24
        single_true_false = digits // 10**single % 10
        true_false.append(single_true_false) 
        environments = zip(distinct,true_false)
        
        if eval(open_file,environments):
            satisfied += 1
        else: 
            not_satisfied += 1            
            
print('Satisfied: ', satisfied, '; Not Satisfied: ', not_satisfied)
```

Comment: What about converting it to string? Then you can iterate over it.

Comment: I mean, `digits = f"removed:length"` is clearly a string (BTW, it's literally the string `"removed:length"`, no formatting is applied!), but you're trying to divide it by something in `digits // 10**single % 10`

Comment: The error in the question is different from the one in the title. Which one are you really getting?

Comment: @Barmar, oops you're right - truth is both are issues -  I getting the one in the description though

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `if eval(open_file,environments)`, but `eval()` is rarely the correct function for anything.

Comment: "How to iterate over an integer?" You don't. That's what the error is telling you. What are you actually trying to do here? What is your goal with this code?

Comment: @Barmar `eval` on a file with unchecked contents...what could go wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is simple: `digits = f"removed:length"` assigns the string value "removed:length" to `digits`.  You can't use that as an operand to an arithmetic operation.

Presumably, since you preceded the string literal with `f`, you wanted to substitute values into the string.  For instance you might have meant to write `digits = f"{removed}:{length}"`. The curly braces indicate to Python where you want substitution to occur.

However, that still wouldn't give you an integer value, and I don't know what integer value you would expect it to give you, given the colon in the middle of the string.  What do you want `digits` to contain?

Comment: I guess he wants to parse `digits` as a binary number, since he's extracting digits from a binary number.

Comment: @Barmar - Exactly! What should I do? How do I turn it into an int?

Comment: @YYB `int(digits, 2)` will parse it as a binary number.

Comment: @Barmar - but then I get an "invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0:8'" for line single_true_false = int(digits, 2) // 10**single % 10

Comment: `f"{removed}:{length}"` should be `f"{removed:{length}}"`

Answer (score 0):

For a 16 bit integer you can use bit shift and compare them with 1 as the bits are shifted right.  Now you have an iterable list.  The original question was how to iterate over an integer.  I think bit by bit is the only answer.

```
xList=[]
x=32768
for i in range(0,16):
    print(x & 1)
    xList.append(x & 1)
    x=x>>1

print(xList)
```

The output is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]